# Dynamo DB Scan Field with value keyword

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to scan a dynamo db table based on a value of a list item that has `value` in it's name. The field is

```
"TPMS.value": {
    "L": [
      {
        "N": "0"
      },
      {
        "N": "0"
      },
      {
        "N": "0"
      },
      {
        "N": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and I'd like to get results where `TPMS.value[0] != 0`
I've tried

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name afdcm-app-demo-Telemetry-Int_Table \
    --filter-expression "TPMS.value[0] > :val"  \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"N":"0"}}'
```

but I keep getting `Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: value`. Is there a way to run the scan where field name contains `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the *--expression-attribute-names* option. According to documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html):

***One or more substitution tokens for attribute names in an expression. The following are some use cases for using ExpressionAttributeNames :***

- ***To access an attribute whose name conflicts with a DynamoDB reserved word.***
- To create a placeholder for repeating occurrences of an attribute name in an expression.
- To prevent special characters in an attribute name from being misinterpreted in an expression.

---

So in your case the command should be similar to this:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name afdcm-app-demo-Telemetry-Int_Table --filter-expression "#VAL[0] > :val" --expression-attribute-names '{"#VAL":"TPMS.value"}' --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"N":"0"}}'
```